# LOAD DATA INFILE giving out error code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to use the following query

```
$query_name = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"
            . $file_path . 
            "' INTO TABLE '"
            . $this->table_name . 
             "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
             IGNORE 1 LINES 
             (time_stamp,curr_property,curr_property_cost,day_property,day_property_cost,curr_solar_generating,curr_solar_export,day_solar_generated,day_solar_export,curr_chan1,curr_chan2,curr_chan3,day_chan1,day_chan2,day_chan3)";
                $this->db->query($query_name);
```

to upload my data into a database but the problem is that I am getting the following error

```
    Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''admin_tmp' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ' at line 1

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'uploads/admin.csv' INTO TABLE 'admin_tmp' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (time_stamp,curr_property,curr_property_cost,day_property,day_property_cost,curr_solar_generating,curr_solar_export,day_solar_generated,day_solar_export,curr_chan1,curr_chan2,curr_chan3,day_chan1,day_chan2,day_chan3)
```

I know that error 1064 is related to syntax but I don't see anything wrong with my code. Will be happy if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks). The table name `admin_tmp` should be unquoted or backtick-quoted, _not_ single quoted.

Comment: Note that if you execute this from the web, you are probably going to need an absolute path to the CSV file. `/path/to/uploads/admin.csv`

Comment: Thanks Mike, for the help and also for the link to the resource.